# How do I set environment properties on Android Apps?

Tags: java, android

My Android App calls a Rest Service, and I would like to choose which environment my app connects to (say local dev, staging or production). Ideally, I would like to have a property (say SERVICE_HOST) and this would have a different value per environment.

In server side Java, I could pass in a JVM variable (-DENVIRONEMNT=production), and the property loader would read the correct property file according to that.

Is there any equivalent approach in Android ? (or an alternative approach that would solve my problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to choose which environment my app connects to (say local dev, staging or production)

If you are using Android Studio, those map to [build types](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types). Two build types are pre-established: `debug` and `release`. You can define more in your `app` module's `build.gradle` file. And, you can define per-build type constants.

For example:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
      applicationIdSuffix ".d"
      buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://test.this-is-so-fake.com"'
    }

    release {
      buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://prod.this-is-so-fake.com"'
    }

    staging.initWith(buildTypes.release)

    staging {
        applicationIdSuffix ".stage"
        debuggable true
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://stage.this-is-so-fake.com"'
    }
}
```

This defines a new build type (`staging`) and creates a `BuildConfig.SERVER_URL` field that you can use as a base for constructing a full URL at runtime.

Your "Build Variants" view in Android Studio (docked by default lower left) will let you choose which build type the "run" and "debug" toolbar buttons actually use.